# Change Emacs M-x shell to use Windows 10 bash

Tags: windows, bash, emacs, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have been using the Windows graphical Emacs for a while, and I am trying to use it along with Windows 10's new-ish Windows Bash. What I want to do is, when I type into Windows Emacs, `M-x shell`, I want it to use the Windows Bash shell, instead of the normal Windows cmd. I tried adding this to my .emacs file:

```
(setq explicit-shell-file-name "C:/path/to/bash.exe")
(setq shell-file-name "bash")
(setq explicit-bash.exe-args '("--noediting" "--login" "-i"))
(setenv "SHELL" shell-file-name)
(add-hook 'comint-output-filter-functions 'comint-strip-ctrl-m)
```

I got it from [here](https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/running-shells-in-emacs-overview). This, when I ran `M-x shell` gave a `Spawning child process: invalid argument` error. I tried omitting the third line, since it was about arguments, but that did nothing. Is there a way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because emacs.stackexchange.com would probably be a better place for it.

Comment: @Barmar: No. There is nothing wrong with posing Emacs questions here. They are not off-topic. Users can choose which site to use, based on whatever criteria they think are important, including likely viewers and their likely knowledge of the question.

Comment: @Drew Well, I think the folks at emacs.stackexchange.com are likely to have better knowledge of how to do esoteric things like using shell mode on Windows.

Comment: This question is mostly about integrating Emacs into the Windows environment, not really about programming.

Comment: StackOverflow is for questions like this - see the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) ("specific programming problems, software algorithms, coding techniques, software development tools". Emacs is a software development tool, if there ever was one. There are 14,632 questions at SO tagged `emacs`. And if a question is not off-topic, it's up to the *questioner* to decide whether "*the folks at emacs.stackexchange.com are likely to have better knowledge*" to answer this question.

Comment: Did you try using a windows-style path, like: (setq explicit-shell-file-name "C:\\path\\to\\bash.exe")

Comment: @kungfushark, stupid question, but you didn't literally use `"C:/path/to/bash.exe"`, right? You substituted the real path?

Comment: @phils yeah I used the actual path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this defun works for me to start up the `WSL` bash shell.

`(defun run-win-ubuntu ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((shell-file-name "C:\\Windows\\System32\\bash.exe" ))
    (shell "*ubuntu*"))
  )`